# portList.hasMoreElements() returns false in serial port

Tags: java, serial-port, windows-8.1, at-command, rxtx

I am working on an application related with serial port and AT commands for SMS sending using Java, I am using windows8.1 64 bit, my code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("here");
    String line1 = "AT+CSMS=1\r\n";
    String line2 = "AT+CMGS=" + dest + "\r\n";
    String line3 = messageString + "\r\n";

    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    System.out.println(portList);

    System.out.println(portList.hasMoreElements());

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {

        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();

        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            if (portId.getName().equals("COM3")) {
                System.out.println("SMS Sending....Port Found");
                try {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWrite", 2000);
                    SimpleWrite wr = new SimpleWrite(serialPort);

                } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                    System.out.println("Port In Use " + e);
                }
                try {
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error writing to output stream " + e);
                }
                try {
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                }
                try {
                    outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line2.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line3.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(26);
                    outputStream.flush();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error writing message " + e);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

This what the output I am getting as follows:

```
C:\>javac SimpleWrite.java

C:\>java SimpleWrite
here
gnu.io.CommPortEnumerator@7852e922
false
```

I am getting the value of `portList`. But the value of `portList.hasMoreElements()` return me `false`. Due to this problem I am unable to continue. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the jar from the link http://mfizz.com/oss/rxtx-for-java for 64 bit version.

Followed the below steps.

For a JDK installation:

Copy RXTXcomm.jar ---> \jre\lib\ext

Copy rxtxSerial.dll ---> \jre\bin

Copy rxtxParallel.dll ---> \jre\bin

Added the jar in my project and when I execute the below lines am getting true

```
Enumeration portL = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
System.out.println(portL);
System.out.println(portL.hasMoreElements());
```

Comment: take a look at operating system and library I am using. I have Windows 8.1, 64bit. So win32com.dll did not come into picture. And I am using RXTX not COMM . Please read carefully before comment. Don't under estimate buddy!!

Comment: Will try and let you know buddy!!

Comment: buddy I had tried but still getting outputs as gnu.io.CommPortEnumerator@7852e922
false . Can you tell what you got??

Comment: true.

1) Are you sure you downloaded the 64bit version jar ?
2) Make sure you copied both the  dlls to the bin of jre not jdk.
3) Also copy the jar file to lib of jre.

Its working fine for me.

Comment: Yah I have downloaded for 64 bit jar file and copied it into jre . I dont know why it is not working in mine. Buddy. portL  is getting some value but portL.hasMoreElements() is returns false,  Can you tell me what may be the reason??

Comment: its false because, as you know there wont be anyport.
Can you please give a details of where you copy pasted the files ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68459/discussion-between-santhucool-and-robin).